# How to loop a sound in Discord JS 13

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord.js

Discord JS got updated to version 13 and the whole voice library has changed. Since the release is relatively fresh code examples are rare. I cannot figure out how to loop a sound correctly. How do you do that in DiscordJS 13?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js')
const DiscordStream = require('@discordjs/voice')

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES]})

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on('messageCreate', message => {
  if (message.content === '/play') {
    const voicechannel = message.member.voice.channel
    const connection = DiscordStream.joinVoiceChannel({
      channelId: voicechannel.id,
      guildId: message.guild.id,
      adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
    })
    const player = DiscordStream.createAudioPlayer()
    connection.subscribe(player)
    
    // player.play(DiscordStream.createAudioResource(Ytstream(url, {filter : 'audioonly'})))
    player.play(DiscordStream.createAudioResource('test.opus'))
    player.on(DiscordStream.AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {
      player.play(DiscordStream.createAudioResource('test.opus'))
      // player.play(DiscordStream.createAudioResource(Ytstream(url, {filter : 'audioonly'})))
    })
  }
})

client.login('your-token here')
```

Connect to an audio channel and use '/play' command. It works for me !

```
npm list
roger@1.0.0 /root/dev/Roger
├── @discordjs/opus@0.6.0
├── @discordjs/voice@0.6.0
├── discord.js@13.2.0
├── sodium@3.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for this documentation. https://discordjs.github.io/voice/
They separate it into it's own independent module.